# Google+ login is not working in my android application when i download it from playstore

Tags: android, authentication, google-play, google-plus

i m working on android applications, i want to login in my application with Google+.
that works fine before publishing my application on Google Play Store.
but when i download my application from store google+ login not woking and showing Toast" an internal error occured " i have followed all the steps.created New project on google developer console , given SHA1 key generated from cmd command (located in .android folder in c drive).then why i fail to login with G+ .pls help out me here.

Comment: Can you share any ADB logs?

Comment: i got solution , there are two SHA1 key one is which we generate with cmd
and 2nd we get while generating signed apk of project.
now, if i use 1st one g+ will run only for my pc
and if i use 2nd one it will run for all.
now i have created two clients on google console and provide these two 
to each one. and it runs....thanku...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create seperate SHA1 keys for debug and production.

The keystore for debug is located inside the eclipse sdk, while for production can be created using the Eclipse-> Export->Android apk option.

Hope it helps!